# EmberJS Component With Graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, highcharts

I have an `emberjs` component that I was hoping to use to generate `Highcharts` graphs with.

For example, I want to be able to do `{{component-name xy_data=data}}` and have a graph generate with that data.

Currently, my template for the component is simple, it looks like

```
<button {{action "confirm"}}>Click again to confirm</button>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
{{yield}}
```

When the user clicks confirm, I use a jQuery callback provided by `Highcharts` to generate the graph for the container. This is very hacky but I can't understand where I should put the logic for this jQuery callback.

For example, do I put it in the route for each route that uses this component? This seems tedious to the developer to remember to do this.

Is there a way that I can have a setup phase in the `component.js` file that changes based on the contents of the model being passed in? To, my understanding there is a `setupController` but this is not available to components.

Comment: I cant say much without seeing ur code but you put all jquery code related to the graph inside the component file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go ahead and initialize the graph when you load the component:

**component.js**

```
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  confirmed: false,
  actions: {
    confirm: function() {
      var component = this;
      component.set("confirmed", true);
    }
  },
  initializeGraph: function() {
    var component = this;
    // code to initialize highcharts graph here
  }.on('didInsertElement')
});
```

**component.hbs**

```
{{#if confirmed}}
  <highcharts graph>
{{else}}
  <button {{action "confirm"}}>Click again to confirm</button>
{{/if}}
```